# gdb: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x#number#

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, gdb

When I try to run debugging on qt-Creator via GDB I allways gain a message in `Application Output` window :

```
no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7fff931fe000
```

The number at the end may be different. 
This message ocure always. For example in "Hello world!" project `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**CMakeList.txt** - generated in qt-Creator by default:

```
project(Cmake_debug_warning)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
```

Do I have pay attention to these messages? What does this message mean?
Forgive me for this stupid question, but I would like to know how to get rid of this?

Im working on

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (64 bit)
- Qt Creator 3.1.2
- GNU gdb (GDB) 7.7.1
- gcc(g++) 4.8.1

Comment: Some symbol is missing... why would you like to get rid of this? You could check which symbol is missing by objdump around the dependencies, I think.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to fix it in Qt-Creator?

Comment: No, I have no idea. To be honest, I would not personally even bother fixing it. ;)

Comment: Maybe you are right. But in other brojects I gain next warnings in `Application Output` window:
`no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7fff3035c000`
`RTTI symbol not found for class "boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<std::string>" ` Do you thisk here no any dependence betwen them?

Comment: Does it go away for no optimization?

Comment: I do not know. I am just tracking my program.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have pay attention to these messages?

No, you can safely ignore them.

> What does this message mean?

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10506452/50617).

Comment: Thanks! Anyway, do I can do somethink to remove those pesky "warnings"?

Comment: @Ivan: This is clearly not an answer; duplicate at its best. Now that you accepted it, it is even more difficult to get it removed. It does not really help you how to get rid of it.